# How to get custom functionality in Django admin. Are there cases where it's recommended to do your own admin page from scratch?

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-admin, e-commerce

This is a quick question for any experienced Django developers.

I have been trying to implement an admin page for 'Products' for an e-commerce store.

My vision for it was to have the top half of that form being used to enter information about a product which is a model I have defined. In the bottom part, I wanted to create some kind of inline to create ProductVariant (which is also a model I have) objects. Within the ProductVariant, I need some type of JavaScript behavior which displays or hides fields based on information entered at the Product section.

My question is would you recommend just completely throwing away the admin framework provided for that specific page and doing my own thing from scratch because I have just been struggling to get the custom functionality I want.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes to get the custom functionality you are describing, you’d probably need to implement, on your own, certain parts of the admin site (most likely overriding the templates). Some people even go as far as creating an entirely new admin site if they intend to work with frameworks like React.

That said, I’d look into the templates of the admin site in the Django libraries and, perhaps, copy most parts of the template then style and and add JavaScript as desired because you might miss certain key elements of the original if you do your own from scratch.